# Looping through array and update variable based on async code

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, async-await

I am trying to loop through an array and calling a promise, and based on that result it updates the variable. The code is working as I wanted but I am concerned if this is a good way to write it. Are there any better ways? Thank you in advance.

```
/**
*
* u/returns Resolves a promise and returns value 'b'
*/
async function generatePromise() {
   return Promise.resolve('b');
}

async function main() {
   let showWarning = false;
   // List of users
   const users = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
   //Looping through users array and compare the result from promise and update showWarning boolean
   await users.reduce(async (promise, user) => {
     await promise;
     const result = await generatePromise();
     if (result === user) showWarning = true;
   }, Promise.resolve())

   console.log(showWarning)
}
main();
```

Comment: can you describe the problem you are trying to solve instead of your potential solution? It do always works better that way when asking for opinions.

Comment: Head over to https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems unnecessarily complicated and the logic is somewhat backwards. Assuming that `generatePromise` will always return the same response, why would you call it multiple times?
Call it once and check whether the value is contained in the array:

```
const showWarning = users.includes(await generatePromise());
```

*If* the function needs to be called multiple times (e.g. because it could potentially return a different response per input/user) then you can use a simple `for` loop:

```js
for (const user of users) {
  if (user === await generatePromise()) {
    showWarning = true;
    break; // why check other users if `showWarning` won't change anymore?
  }
}
```